# Various shades of colours

Tags: color

I'm trying out the code and would like to generate a pattern with different shades of colours, so "r" would not only be Red, but "r1" would be Light Red, "r2" might be Red and "r3" might be a darker red. Then the same for "g" etc. Does anyone think something like this is possible here?

Thanks in advance.

María.

Comment: Try simply `r1=LightRed; r2=Red; r3=Darker[Red];` and use them the same way you use the ordinary `Red`. And the same for g.

Comment: For fifty shades of grey see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45764)  ([Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)).